# Midnight Commander: How to format file size as a number with digit group separators?

Tags: mc

When dealing with large files in Midnight Commander, I have difficulties counting the digits to get the order of magnitude of the file size (hundreds of MB, or tens of GB, etc.).

Sometimes, I use the trick to press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, which highlights the file and shows the file size in a nicely formatted way (i.e., as a number with [digit group separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator); e.g., `123,456,789`), which makes it much more readable.

I am wondering if/how I could set up MC to show the file size in this format by default, in the `Size` column.

I assume this has nothing to do with `locale`.

Comment: Related MC ticket: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3165 Ticket #3165 Display human readable sizes in panels

Comment: Of course this request ***is*** locale-sensitive.  Specifically, in the Indian locale (set `LANG` or `LC_NUMERIC` to `en_IN` or `en_IN.UTF-8`, for example), 123456789 is displayed as “12,34,56,789”.

Answer (score 14):

You can adjust the displayed digits with the column `size` option, see the “Listing mode” section in the manual. The file to edit is `~/.config/mc/panels.ini`.

To list the file sizes as `K`, `M` or `G` use a narrow size column using the `user_format` key:

```
[New Left Panel]
user_format=half type name mark size:4 space mtime
```

If you want the size without abbreviation, reserve enough space for it:

```
[New Right Panel]
user_format=half type name mark size:16 space mtime
```

Comment: but this will not display the filesize as: `123,456,789`

Comment: You didn't exactly specify what you want, you said “nicely formatted”. What is wrong with this, is it the missing comma?

Comment: 123,456,789 is what I would like to have

Comment: You should add, that the changes are only visible by setting the Listing mode for each panel to custom. `Left -> Listing mode... -> (*) User defined:`

Comment: after edited the `~/.config/mc/panels.ini` i start the `mc` but it doesn't show as you said? do I need to run something like `source ~/.bashrc` to notify mc to update the config?

Comment: I wanted to know how to make mc display file sizes in human-readable format. This answer does exactly that. Thanks @Marco.